# Model Performance in Deep Learning

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

May I know should I stop the training process at epoch 19, since the overfitting happens right after that.

Or it is still ok to be used since the difference is not too big.

I would like to ask for clarification regarding how small is the difference should we stop the training process.

Thank you.

[Graph of "Loss vs Epoch" and "Acc vs Epoch"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kuVP.png)

Answer (score 0):

i guess, i'd like to know more about your problem, your network architecture and so on, but given what you provided, i would test first with different batch sizes before making any decision about stopping at epoch 19. Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/deep-learning-experiments/effect-of-batch-size-on-neural-net-training-c5ae8516e57).

Comment: Fyi, I am training a Siamese Network where MobileNetv2 is used as the baseline. Dataset consists of 187629 images (Divided into 8:2 train:test). 

Here is the model summary https://drive.google.com/file/d/13S3PENTVarH2oKI5Gc63aIQxRAvrGyvF/view?usp=sharing

Batch size is 32 with step_per_epoch is 1000. Also batch size=32 is my GPU limit.

Feel free to ping me if more info is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should study early stopping; this article can help you learn more about [Early Stopping to avoid overfitting](https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/early-stopping-to-avoid-overfitting-in-neural-network-keras-b68c96ed05d9#:%7E:text=Early%20stopping%20is%20a%20method,improving%20on%20the%20validation%20dataset.). It can help you not worry about the number of epochs and the value of the loss.